# comments plugin moderation tool not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I'm trying to set up the Facebook comments social plugin. The plugin will be set up so that each product page on our site will have a comments plugin with a unique URL. I want to be able to moderate all the comments together, which should be able to be done with the comments moderator tool on Facebook.

I can put the social plugin on the page with it linked to the respective app ID, but I don't see any comments appear on the moderation tool at: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

The code on the page is this:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript">
  (function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=[appid]";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Then later...

```html
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="[appdid]"/>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.testtesttest.com/" data-num-posts="2" data-width="" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

It's important to note that for now I'm actually using the URL `testtesttest.com`, but I am putting in my actual app ID in the app ID spots.

I do this and can post comments to the page fine. However, I see nothing in the moderation tool. Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong? Has anyone gotten this to work successfully? I'm not sure if my app is set up wrong, or there is a url match issue, or domain issue. I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm following this one too.  I've got the same issues with comment moderation and I'm even specifying fb admin ids too and having the fb admin like the page (per the documentation) and still nothing.

Comment: It's unclear if you own `testtesttest.com` or not. If the `app_id` tag is not present ON `testtesttest.com` then it won't work. Otherwise you could just put any old URL and moderate comments for other people's sites.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. I was debugging on my local machine, and it seems that the facebook admin integration wouldn't work there. Once I moved it to a production/visible server the debugger worked: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I was then able to troubleshoot the main problems and get the comments integrated. It's odd because the commenting itself will work locally. Live and learn I guess.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and solved it with this:

For moderation tool to work, beside app

```html
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxx" />
```

and admin tags

```html
<meta property="fb:admins" content="xxx" />
```

you MUST add the  tags:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="URL" />
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE" />
<meta property="og:description" content="DESC" />
<meta property="og:image" content="IMG" />
```

after that everything worked fine.

Comment: Dont forget:  <meta property="og:type" content="TYPE"/> and <meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE NAME"/>

Comment: To see changes imidietly, refresh facebook cache by fetching your url with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
Without it i saw no changes (no moderation view)

Comment: which of these are really NEEDED. You REALLY NEED image for comments to work? that just makes no sense. Did you confirm 100% this is true?

Comment: also according to comments plugin https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments you're supposed to provide `app_id` OR `fb:admins` but not both

Comment: Not all of these properties need to be set. You need to set app_id only. After setting app_id on page as Michael has suggested go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ page and scrape the page again then only you get to see the changes.

Comment: Must have `og:url`, etc? Is this stated in documentation anywhere?

Answer (score 8):

I tried these solutions but they didn't work for me. After several hours I found the solution. This is the process I followed:

1. I went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, put the URL of my app where I had the facebook comments box
2. The most important information is the final url because this is the page where facebook will look for your meta tags "Final URL is in bold (this is the URL we tried to extract metadata from)".
3. I noticed that my final url was my sign in page, but I didn't have my meta tags in my sign in page! I had just added the meta tags in the layout I used for facebook comments.
4. I just added the `fb:app_id` meta tag with my facebook app id in my sign in page, and I finally have my Comment Moderation Tool working.

Answer (score 4):

I am using this meta tags.

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="TİTLE" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="CONTENT" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="İMAGE URL" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="000xxx"/> 
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="11xxx"/>
```

First time,comments plugin moderation tool was not working in my page too.

**Important!** You must add this tag to html code of page.

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

Then, wait several minute. Write something. Plugin will working.

P.S. Of course you must use "app id" in the javascript codes.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript">
    (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=[APP İD]";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

No extra tags needed. All it needs it a break of an hour. **FB is slow**, not sure what it does for an hour but it starts working after some time. Just like some of your friends post show up on your feed much later than they posted. **It is working for me** after so much of internet reading but with no changes to code (as per original FB documentation code).
here is what needs to be done.

> Include meta tags in your header file

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>
```

> add code in your html page

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470"></div>
```

> Most importantly, take a long break and dont forget to ctrl+F5 your
>   pages when you come back. I hate this wait time, and so will you.

Comment: Facebook shows changes as per the data it has scraped for that page and it's not scraping data frequently so you have to wait. If you don't want to take a break then go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ enter your page URL and "Scrape Again". It will start reflecting your changes instantly.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said IT TAKES TIME for FB to catch up **even if you try to trigger the OG parser** at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object.

One thing not mentioned by others is to **make sure you are actually an admin of the app**. I wasn't explicitly listed even though I had create the app myself. So to be sure I added myself here :

[image]

Also add some black listed words and enable review. From **a non-admin** account you can then put a comment like `this product sucks` and see if it appears in the review queue. If an admin uses a blocked word it will still appear.

[image]

Comment: 100% true.. After adding myself as moderator, only then i could see that Moderation tool in comment box and hide people's comment. Thankyou for this.. Wasted more than 5 hours, this helped!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is re-indexing (scraping)
1. Open https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/
2. Enter and check url
3. Look at section "When and how we last scraped the URL"

If page is not scraped new comments will not be shown in moderation panel.
After I have pressed button "Scrape again" comments works fine. Don't forget re-scrape each existing page (new pages works fine).

Answer (score 2):

Solution if you get the following error on the [object debugger page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/):

> ...'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

---

### Using fb:admins with the user slug instead of the user ID

I had the same problem and I don't now why the numeric user ID was not working.

I fixed it using my user "slug" (user name, the alpha numeric one) instead of my user ID (the numeric one).

You can find you user "slug" when accessing a user timeline:

www.facebook.com/**first-name.last-name**

Then update your page with:

```html
<meta property="fb:admins" content="first-name.last-name" />
```

Check that everything is ok on the Facebook object debugger page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Click the "fetch new scrape information" button.

And that's it, go back to your page and enjoy the moderation feature.

Answer (score 1):

FB Moderation of COMMENTS ISSUE RESOLVED

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="YourFBID"/>
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="YOURAPP ID" />
Specify the meta tags in the head

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=yourAppId";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

 <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php 'YourURL'; ?>" data-num-posts="2" data-width="470" data-colorscheme="light" data-mobile="false"></div>
```

data-href in the above holds the key for moderation tool.. Its should be just as i have done... Something with the php tags it is.

Answer (score 1):

This only worked for me when I changed my `data-href` to `https`. My app doesn't want to connect unless my url is https. My site does have ssl but comments were already configured with the `http` urls.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APP_ID}" />
```

or

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID_1}"/>
```

on your website.
(put it above all the code and stuff)
check it on

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
```

if fb:admin or fb:app id is showing.
If it is showing and your website is https.. You will get the moderation option. Else, it will not work