# Facebook comment moderation implemented but not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I needed a comment plugin with moderation feature, As I check the docs I can do it with fb comment plugin.

I have followed the documentation and attach fb comment plugin created from one of my app. Used the below code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src ="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10&appId=5XXXXXXXXXXXXX4";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
   </script>
```

And for the comment I have added

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://my.domain.com/folder/subfolder/page-1" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

Meta tags on the page are as follows

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="5XXXXXXXXXXXXXX4" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://my.domains.com/folder/subfolder/page-1" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://my.domain.com/folder/abc.jpg" />
```

My FB App has domain set to ***my.domain.com*** and the site url of website set to ***http://my.domain.com***

I can see the comment plugin on the page and post with fb login all fine.

But I want comment moderation in this plugin, I am checking here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/5XXXXXXXXXXXXXX4/ for comments to show/moderate but no comment is shown under this app.

I have took reference from the following questions, but none can resolve my problem

- [Facebook comment moderation tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797660/facebook-comment-moderation-tool)
- [Can't get the Facebook comment moderation to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280784/cant-get-the-facebook-comment-moderation-to-work)
- [comments plugin moderation tool not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120814/comments-plugin-moderation-tool-not-working)

Please suggest any solution

Comment: Have you checked your OG meta tags using the debug tool yet?

Comment: yes i have and it all comes fine, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmy.domain.com%2Ffolder%2Fsubfolder%2Fpage-1,

P.S. I have used real urls instead of given above.
Also I have implemented the same yesterday, so there shouldn't be case of caching by facebook, to be sure I have scraped the url now as well